# Facial Recognition

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I need an algorithm that can do facial recognition in a video based on a training set. For any faces detected, it should give an output as how much the face matches with the faces in the training set.
 How can this be done ?

Comment: You are on the wrong site for this.

Comment: Sounds like a recipe for gazillions of false positives.